# Remove brackets with unknown content in MYSQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a large MYSQL table with an unknown amount of bracketed numbers.

Ex: "Now the earth was [1] formless and empty..."

The number can be up to 3 digits.

Is it possible to write a query that removes both the brackets and the numbers when I don't know what the numbers will be?

Comment: Yes, using regular expressions for example.

Comment: @str MySQL does not support regex replacement natively. It must be done either with very nasty string manips, or on the application side unless non standard user functions are installed

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope it can help you:

```
<?php
$str = "Just random [4] stuff with [56] random nums [000]" ;     
$clean = preg_replace("/(\[[0-9]+\])/", "", $str) ;

echo $clean ; //Outputs: Just random  stuff with  random nums
?>
```

Fetch data from database and do the replacement.

Or you could just write a script to modify your database values:
Fetch identificators and strings with `SELECT`. 
Then perform replacement. Update your table in the database using `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-time thing you can do following:

- dump your table to a file `mysqldump -u user -p dbname --no-create-info mytable > /tmp/mytabledump.sql`
- using `sed` do your replacement `sed -e 's/\[\([0-9]*\)\]//g' mytabledump.sql > mytableclean.sql`
- truncate your table `mysql -u user -p dbname -e "TRUNCATE TABLE mytable;"`
- import data `mysql -u user -p dbname < /tmp/mytableclean.sql`

You might need to tweak regexp a bit.